# nginx: [emerg] cannot load certificate "/etc/letsencrypt/live/api.domain.com/fullchain.pem"

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

I have generated fullchain.pem, privkey, ssl-dhparams locally and then saved to the nginx folder which I am copying from to docker nginx container. With the below setup, I am getting issue of `nginx: [emerg] cannot load certificate "/etc/letsencrypt/live/api.domain.com/fullchain.pem" failed (SSL: error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:fopen('/etc/letsencrypt/live/api.domain.com/fullchain.pem','r') error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file`

nginx.dockerfile

```
FROM nginx

COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY fullchain.pem /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.domain.com/fullchain.pem
COPY privkey.pem /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.domain.com/privkey.pem
COPY options-ssl-nginx.conf /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf
COPY ssl-dhparams.pem /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem
```

nginx.conf

```
http {
  include mime.types;
  default_type application/octet-stream;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log combined;
  sendfile on;
  upstream app_server {
      server backend:8080 fail_timeout=0;
      # server APP_SERVER_2_IP;
  }

  server {
      listen 80 default_server;
      return 444;
  }

  server {
      listen 80;
      listen [::]:80;
      server_name api.domain.com;
      return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
  }

  server {
      server_name api.domain.com;

      client_max_body_size 4G;
      keepalive_timeout 5;
      location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass http://app_server;
      }
      listen 443 ssl http2;
      listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
      # SSL
      ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.domain.com/fullchain.pem;
      ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.domain.com/privkey.pem;
      include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
      ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

  }
}
```

why am I getting such issue?

UPDATE:

Sorry, I mismatched the name while copying my code. I have updated with it now.

Comment: so does this file exist?

Comment: Are the permission of the files set correctly? maybe chmod 777 needed!

Comment: Check if the files `fullchain.pem` and `privkey.pem` are in the same directory as `Dockerfile`. Also, why don't you install `certbot` in your `nginx` container so that it will be renewed automatically each 90 days?

Comment: they are on the same directory. Can you please elaborate the way to use certbot instead?

Comment: @rezshar where should I do chmod?

Comment: Use `chmod 777 /etc/letsencrypt/live -R`  to test this; Opening the file access level may cause security problems, but for this method, it has always solved my problem

Comment: do I need to add this line before `COPY fullchain.pem /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.domain.com/fullchain.pem` statement?

Comment: Add `RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y certbot`, then RUN `certbot certonly --webroot -w ABS_PATH_TO_YOUR_SITE -d DOMAIN_NAME -d WWW.DOMAIN_NAME --agree-tos -m YOUR_EMAIL` and it will create the file and every other thing. I think since you did not make any dir in `/etc/letsencrypt/...`, you're getting `no such file ...` error. Did you create that?

Comment: Sorry, I missed to create a file. Thanks for certbot usage, however I used certbot image instead.

Answer (score 2):

seems like the path is wrong where you copied the cert is different that where you nginx configuration is pointing

```
COPY fullchain.pem /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.codolytics.com/fullchain.pem
COPY privkey.pem /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.codolytics.com/privkey.pem
```

now in nginx config its a different path

```
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.domain.com/fullchain.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.domain.com/privkey.pem;
```

Comment: Sorry, it should be api.domain.com. I mismatched the name while copying the code.